# openssl RSASSA-PSS signature API

Tags: c, cryptography, digital-signature

We are asked to switch our signature scheme to RSASSA-PSS.
I found the EVP_digestsignXXX family of functions, but this seems to merge the digest calculation step with the signature step.
Our project requires to output both digest and signature, not just the signature.

How can we get both digest and signature?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am not allowed to copy code here. However:
I found this one: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:EVP_PKEY_sign(3)
so I plan to compute the digest manually , then use the above function, so I have access to both the digest AND the signature.

Comment: updated link: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_PKEY_sign.html